# how to use collation with mongodb and dart?

Tags: mongodb, dart, mongo-dart

I need to make insensitive sorting in a find command within mongodb. It is possible with mongodb >= 3.4 using the collation method:

```
db.myCollection.find({city: "new york"}).collation({locale: "en", strength: 2})
```

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

However, I can't seem to find the option using mongodart: 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart

Comment: Please open an issue, so we can eventually bring this about. I'm one of the maintainers (although admittedly busy these days).

Comment: @TobeO, there is already an issue for that subject: https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/issues/107. Maybe you can give me directions on how to use collation within the cursors and I can PR once I make it work